# If $a \cdot a = 1$ then $a = 1$ or $a = -1$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field.

And let $a \in F$ such that $a \cdot a = 1$.

**Claim:** $a = 1$ or $ a = -1$

Before, I begin with the proof I cannot understand what $ a = -1$ represents...

Is $a = -1$ representing the inverse of $a$?

I am capable of getting to $a = 1$ with no trouble, but how do you get the $-$ sign to show up in your proof?

**Proof:** This is my attempt at getting to $a=-1$.

If $a = 0$ then we have $0 \cdot 0 = 0 \neq 1$. Then this implies that $a \neq 0$ which implies that $ \exists b \in F,$ s.t. $a \cdot b = 1$, i.e. $b$ is the multiplicative inverse of $a$.

Knowing this fact prove as follows...:

$a \cdot a = 1 \implies$ $ (a \cdot a) \cdot b = 1 \cdot b \implies$ $a \cdot (a \cdot b) = 1 \cdot b \implies$ $a \cdot 1 = 1 \cdot b \implies$ $ 1 \cdot a =1 \cdot b \implies$ $a = b$.

But since $b$ is the multiplicative inverse of $a$ is this enough to say that $a = -1$?

Comment: The element $a$ satisfies $a^2-1=0$, or $(a-1)(a+1)=0.$ If you can show that in a field, you cannot multiply two nonzero elements and get $0,$ then you have either $a-1=0$ or $a+1=0. \qquad$

Comment: I know you are bringing the 1 to the other side of the equation, but my **main point** of the question is do we know that $-1$ is the additive inverse of $1$? Shouldn't we call it something else (maybe $b$) since we only know that $0,1 \in F$?

Comment: $a=-1$ means the same thing it has done since you first learned to use letters in math. Nothing fancy going on at all. The letter $a$ represents the number $-1$. That's all it says.

Comment: I think I know what my problem is; Sorry, it takes so many points for me even know what my own problem is. Isn't it technically wrong for you guys to say $a \cdot a = a^2$ because I believe none of axioms, supports that $a \cdot a = a^2$? Another question is, I read the definition of the field once again, when the definition states that $0,1 \in F$ where $0 \neq 1$, are the $0,1$ we are referring to here the actual number $0$ and $1$ or could we have replaced them with any other symbols?

Comment: @Skypanties: What on earth do you mean? The notation $a^2$ is **by definition** an abbreviation for $a \cdot a$.

Comment: @Skypanties: By the way, your argument only shows that $a$ is its own multiplicative inverse, which was obvious from the outset, since that is exactly what the equation $a \cdot a=1$ says. So you are nowhere near proving $a=\pm 1$ yet. Michael Hardy's proof is the way to go. Regarding your doubts about $-1$, it is just **notation** for the additive inverse of $1$ (which is guaranteed to exist, by the field axioms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Before, I begin with the proof I cannot understand what $a=−1$ represents...

You do not have to overthink thinks.
The inverse of $a$ is $(-a)$. And $a=-1$ just means, that $a=-1$.
Calculations work in every field the same. 
It does not matter if you have $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{Q}$ or a finite field like $\mathbb{F}_2$, which is the field with two elements $0$ and $1$.

Finite fields can be confusing at first, there it would actually be $1=-1$ which looks odd at first.

But to make $(\mathbb{F}_2, +,\cdot)$ a field we have to calculate like this:

$0$ is the neutral element of $+$ and $1$ the neutral element of $\cdot$.

Hence $0+0=0$ and $1+0=1$ and $0\cdot 1=0$ and $1\cdot 1=1$.
What is $1+1$? It has to be $1+1=0$!
Because if we had $1+1=1$ we had $1=0$ after subtracting $1$ on both sides. But this contradicts that 0 and 1 are different, which they are by the axioms of a field. (Neutral elements of addition and multiplication are unique).

This means 1 is its own inverse and therfor $1=-1$ which is just notation at that point.

Just as a little "introduction".

To solve your question you can simply go like this:

$a^2-1=0\Leftrightarrow (a+1)(a-1)=0$

This is true in every field!

You might have shown, that $a\cdot b=0\Leftrightarrow a=0\vee b=0$ holds in a field.

Hence $a+1=0\vee a-1=0\Leftrightarrow a\in\{-1,1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

A field is basically an additive group together with a multiplicative group that plays nicely with the additive one. The additive group is usually denoted with operator $+$, and the inverse function of that group is usually denoted with the operator $-$, so that $-a$ is defined to be the additive inverse of $a$ in the group. It may be the case that $-a = a$ (e.g. in any field of characteristic 2, this is true for all $a$). Indeed, $-$ may not have anything at all to do with the subtraction on $\mathbb{Z}$ that you're used to.

You need to show that $a^2 = 1$ implies $a = 1$ or $a = -1$; equivalently, if you're squeamish about minus signs, that $a = 1$ or $a + 1 = 0$. Those two formulations are exactly the same.

(And, to drive this home again, it's possible for $a = 1$ and $a = -1$ to be simultaneously true! In the field $\mathbb{F}_2$ of two elements, $1 = -1$; and it's true in any field of characteristic $2$.)